# Change Image background of button When in Runtime. C# wpf. Which will depend on database

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this code where I can change the content of the button according to the data in my database.

```
using (MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT GarmentName FROM tblthesis", conn))
{
    ds = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(ds);
    MainWindow mainWin = new MainWindow();
    foreach (DataRow dataRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
    {
        Button button = new Button();
        button.Content = dataRow[0].ToString();
        button.BorderThickness = new Thickness(7, 7, 7, 7);
        button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
        button.Width = 195;

        mainWin.sp.Children.Add(button);
    }
}
```

I have tried changing the image but without a database using this code.

```
 var IB= new ImageBrush();
 IB.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Images/myImage.png", UriKind.Relative)); 
 btnSample.Background = IB;
```

can someone help me change background image according to my database?

Comment: "Can someone help me change background image according to my database". How do think that would be possible when you don't tell us what kind of data you have in your database? Is it a BLOB containing an encoded image, or a path to an image file, or probably just some value that selects from a set of predefined images?

Comment: It is a BLOB containing encoded image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to create a BitmpImage from a byte array:

```
byte[] imageBuffer = ... // read this as BLOB from your DB

var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();

using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(imageBuffer))
{
    bitmapImage.BeginInit();
    bitmapImage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
    bitmapImage.StreamSource = memoryStream;
    bitmapImage.EndInit();
}

btnSample.Background = new ImageBrush(bitmapImage);
```

Comment: Hi can you please give me an example code of your, 
byte[] imageBuffer = ... // read this as BLOB from your DB
I'm kinda interested in you code. Thank You

Comment: I don't have your db, but it should look like `var imageBuffer = (byte[])dataRow["<column name>"];`

Comment: Sorry, that's not the way StackOverflow works. You have to show the relevant parts of your code here in your question. Edit the question or write a new one.

Comment: I am sorry sir, It's just I'm exhausted, 
can you please insert your code in my code provided? my column name of my DB is "Image", 
because it's not working for me.

Comment: This is beyond the scope of the question, but `var imageBuffer = (byte[])dataRow["Image"];` inside your forach loop should work.

Comment: Tried it but still not working! It just overlaps with my code, when I put it inside my foreach loop above my (Button new Button) line.

Comment: Why not write a new question with the exact problem?